# Игровой сервер

Tags: html, сервер, sql

Я решил поставить игровой сервер и у меня встал вопрос: собственно, как создать сайт для игрового сервера, и собственно, как создать сам сервер, желательно что-то типа пособия для чайников, по html и установке sql.

Answer (score 1):

Игровой сервер чего?

1. CS
2. WOW
3. On-Line игры

Тут вариантов море, какими средствами располагаете?

> желательно что то типа пособия длячайников, по html и установке sql

Если такой вопрос задан, то не считаю что нужно браться за это дело, загоните себя в угол сразу.

**//upd**

купите выделенный сервер. Но вот по поводу "уже есть образ сервака" он конфигурируется под определенное железо или ему пофиг на чем работать?

Comment: Сервер для muonline season 6, у меня уже имеется собственно сама болванка сервера, с которой я уже работал, MYSQL 2008, и возможность бесплатно сделать домен с тем именем, который мне нужен, единственное я не занимался до этого сайтом и я не ставил собственно сам сервер, а работал под руководством более опытного админа уже с готовым и запущенным сервером...